# Get clipboard file content with Python

Tags: python, file, clipboard, rdp

I'm struggling with read the clipboard content with Python, this is the thing, I need to get the data from the clipboard, but this is a file, this file is located in a RDP which can copy paste the files in my own machine, but, I do this manually and works perfectly, but I can't make it from a Py script. I tried with different methods, and this one is the last try I made:

```
import win32clipboard
import pyperclip
import os
from tkinter import Tk

# Using win32clipboard library
# Get Clipboard info (Only get text)
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard() # Open clipboard
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard() # Close clipboard
print(data)

# Using pyperclip (Only get text, again)
contenidoClipboard = pyperclip.paste()
print(contenidoClipboard)
# Validate if the clipboard content is a file
if contenidoClipboard and os.path.isfile(contenidoClipboard):
    print("File Founded")
else:
    print("This is not that easy!")
    print(contenidoClipboard)

# Get the clipboard info using Tkinter (Only get text AGAIN!!!!!!!!)
print(Tk().clipboard_get())
```

I don't even know if this can be done with Python, so, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Copy and past with [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/):

```
import pyperclip

pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
pa = pyperclip.paste()
print(pa)
```